# Spring Data – Pagination of a native query that uses CTE

Tags: postgresql, pagination, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, common-table-expression

I am using Spring and Postgres.  I have two related entities: UserProfile and Post that have a one to many relationship.  I want to order UserProfiles by the number of posts.

The basic query looks like this (and it works as desired):

```
WITH num_posts AS (SELECT f.profile_id, COUNT(1) post_count FROM post f GROUP BY profile_id) SELECT DISTINCT * FROM profiles INNER JOIN num_posts ON profile_id=user_id ORDER BY post_count DESC
```

I want the results as a Spring Page.  The Repository function looks like this:

```
@Query(value = "WITH num_posts AS (SELECT f.profile_id, COUNT(1) post_count FROM post f GROUP BY profile_id) SELECT DISTINCT * FROM profiles INNER JOIN num_posts ON profile_id=user_id ORDER BY post_count DESC",
countQuery = "WITH num_posts AS (SELECT f.profile_id, COUNT(1) post_count FROM post f GROUP BY profile_id) SELECT DISTINCT count(*) FROM profiles INNER JOIN num_posts ON profile_id=user_id ORDER BY post_count DESC",
nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserProfile> findAllWithPageableOrderByPosts(Pageable pageable);
```

If the results are less than the number of elements per page (ex. 10 profiles but 15 elements per page), there is no issue and the results are returned.  However, if the total results exceed the elements per page (ex. 20 profiles but 15 elements per page), there is the following error:

```
ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

As best as I can tell, the issue seems to be the countQuery possibly related to the count().  However, I have not found any relevant answers in my searches.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is your second query that makes no sense (I omit the `WITH` for clarity):

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(*)
FROM profiles
   INNER JOIN num_posts ON profile_id = user_id
ORDER BY post_count DESC;
```

**First** you count (which incidentally produces a single number), **then** you want to lump equal counts together, and **then** you want the result sorted by something that may be different for each row that gets lumped into one.

If you want the total count, do

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT *)
FROM profiles
   INNER JOIN num_posts ON profile_id = user_id;
```